# Topbar help link to SO Business uses https; pictures are missing

Tags: bug, status-completed, ssl, stackoverflow-business

When clicking on Help in the top-bar and then selecting Business, the URL points to https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/?ref=topbar_help.

[image]

This leads to some images not being displayed properly (highlighted below).

[image]

However, loading this under http:// protocol shows up just fine.

[image]

Comment: Is it fix for [this issue](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/320724/unwanted-image-title-in-the-business-page) causing the bug?

Comment: @Adam how is this not about the top bar? I added the tag then noticed you removed it.

Comment: @ShadowWizard The relevant bug is that the Business page is broken on HTTP. The link in the top bar is fine.

Comment: The broken image issue has been fixed but only by making the site overall http instead of https. In this case, we still need to make sure the top bar isn't pointing to the https version until we can restore the business site to https.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm a new developer at Stack Overflow. As Jon mentioned, the broken image issue has been fixed. We also just updated the topbar link to use HTTP. We'll revisit going back to HTTPS after we finish with a scheduled CDN migration.

Comment: Another SO employee with out diamond symbol?

Comment: @Arulkumar they all start without diamond, usually getting it within 6-8 weeks. (takes lots of time to mine diamonds, you know.)

Comment: @Arulkumar Most employees don't need moderator access. They are not in any way a "lesser" employee than those of us who do.

Comment: @Adam A user changing to `status-*` tag without diamond symbol is causing the confusion.

Comment: @Arulkumar When in doubt, always check the user profile. As the company grows larger, this is only going to become more and more standard.